# Loop with async wait operation weirdness

Tags: c#, wpf, sockets, async-await

I have the following client listener that pass the client to HandleStationClients. The constructor of HandleStationClients starts a Task with the connection in other thread for listening.

The code below runs on the main thread with async function. When a client connects the awaiting part below will continue and passes the client to new created HandleStationClients and hook the events.
Normally after wiring the events the loop will start over and wait for a new connection at the await.
The problem is that this code loop twice for each connection. So client connects and HandleStationClients will created and events will be hooked and while loop starts again and then continue to run the same process creating again a new HandleStationClients and event hooks.

After the client is processed the awaiter is not waiting but continuing for a second time.The events are fired twice. I dont know whats wrong. Any one have a clue?

```
while (true)
{
    counter += 1;

    // Wait for new connection then do rest
    stationsClientSocket = await stationsServerSocket.AcceptTcpClientAsync();

    stationClients.Add(stationsClientSocket, 0);
    Debug.WriteLine("Client toegevoegd " + counter);

    HandleStationClients stationClient = new HandleStationClients(stationsClientSocket);

    stationClient.ConnectionEstabilished += stationClient_ConnectionEstabilished;
    stationClient.ConnectionClosed += stationClient_ConnectionClosed;
    stationClient.NewDataReceived += stationClient_NewDataReceived;
}
```

The HandleClient looks like

```
class HandleStationClients
{
    public HandleStationClients(TcpClient client)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { ProcessConnection(client); });
    }

    #region Event definitions
    public delegate void NewDataReceivedEventHandler(string newData);
    public event NewDataReceivedEventHandler NewDataReceived;

    public delegate void ConnectionClosedEventHandler();
    public event ConnectionClosedEventHandler ConnectionClosed;

    public delegate void ConnectionEstabilishedEventHandler(IPEndPoint endpoint);
    public event ConnectionEstabilishedEventHandler ConnectionEstabilished;
    #endregion

    public async void ProcessConnection(TcpClient stationsClientSocket)
    {
        byte[] message = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;

        NetworkStream networkStream = stationsClientSocket.GetStream();

        if (this.ConnectionEstabilished != null)
        {
            this.ConnectionEstabilished((IPEndPoint)stationsClientSocket.Client.RemoteEndPoint);
        }

        while ((true))
        {
            bytesRead = 0;

            try
            {
                bytesRead = await networkStream.ReadAsync(message, 0, 1024);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // some error hapens here catch it                    
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                break;
            }

            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {
                //the client has disconnected from the server
                break;
            }

            ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();

            if (this.NewDataReceived != null)
            {
                byte[] buffer = null;

                string incomingMessage = encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead);

                this.NewDataReceived(incomingMessage);
            }
        }
        stationsClientSocket.Close();
        // Fire the disconnect Event
        this.ConnectionClosed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem. It's too hard to work out what's going on from just this snippet.

Comment: I agree with Jon. I tried running a short console application that did this and it worked fine.

Comment: I don't think it's much use to make a(n entire) Task an async method.

Comment: @Shift, then you should either answer this question by yourself, or maybe delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bad idea to start the task in the constructor. This means your task is running while you are registering the event handlers. There is a decent chance that sometime you won't get an event registered before it needs to be fired.

What you should do is wait to start the task until the event handlers are all registered. You will need to create a `Start` method to take care of starting the task, and have the code call it once the events are registered.

The updated class:

```
class HandleStationClients
{
    // Added a field to store the value until the Start method
    TcpClient _client;

    public HandleStationClients(TcpClient client)
    {
        this._client = client;
        // Moved the line from here...
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        // ...to here.
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { ProcessConnection(_client); });
    }

    #region Event definitions
    // ...
    #endregion

    public async void ProcessConnection(TcpClient stationsClientSocket)
    {
        byte[] message = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;

        NetworkStream networkStream = stationsClientSocket.GetStream();

        if (this.ConnectionEstabilished != null)
        {
            this.ConnectionEstabilished((IPEndPoint)stationsClientSocket.Client.RemoteEndPoint);
        }

        while ((true))
        {
            bytesRead = 0;

            try
            {
                bytesRead = await networkStream.ReadAsync(message, 0, 1024);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // some error hapens here catch it                    
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                break;
            }

            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {
                //the client has disconnected from the server
                break;
            }

            ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();

            if (this.NewDataReceived != null)
            {
                byte[] buffer = null;

                string incomingMessage = encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead);

                this.NewDataReceived(incomingMessage);
            }
        }
        stationsClientSocket.Close();
        // Fire the disconnect Event
        // I added a line to check that ConnectionClosed isn't null
        if (this.ConnectionClosed != null)
        {
            this.ConnectionClosed();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you need to change the calling code as follows.

```
while (true)
{
    counter += 1;

    // Wait for new connection then do rest
    stationsClientSocket = await stationsServerSocket.AcceptTcpClientAsync();

    stationClients.Add(stationsClientSocket, 0);
    Debug.WriteLine("Client toegevoegd " + counter);

    HandleStationClients stationClient = new HandleStationClients(stationsClientSocket);

    stationClient.ConnectionEstabilished += stationClient_ConnectionEstabilished;
    stationClient.ConnectionClosed += stationClient_ConnectionClosed;
    stationClient.NewDataReceived += stationClient_NewDataReceived;
    // Call Start manually
    stationClient.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I moved the Task start away from the constructor to a Start method. problem is solved.